# Cannot Deselect objects in when other objects are behind the selected Ones

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools

I can select the objects in all the modes, but I just **can't deselect**. (I even tried deselect in box select,circle select and the default <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> but nothing works.)

So if I select something which I didn't want to, I have to deselect the entire scene with A, and then go on again.

I forgot to mention one key thing, that I can deselect objects, but only when there are objects behind it I can't. Unfortunately my scene is a bit complex and has many objects behind each other and hence I just **couldn't deselect any of the selected.**

Comment: Use a side view, or rotate your scene, or deselect using the outliner...

Comment: What happens if you deselect as usual with Middle Mouse button? Did you change User Preferences? You could also use Alt+RMB to open Select menu and choose which object to select (names of the object matter here). You can also use it to add selection.

Comment: This is still an issue in 2.93, makes no sense. I figured out you can deselect by control and drag-selecting though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ‘hide’ (<kbd>H</kbd>) and ‘unhide’ (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) keyboard shortcuts to hide the objects that are getting in the way.

For example, select all the “in front” objects that you don’t want to work on and press <kbd>H</kbd>. If there are more objects then select those and again press <kbd>H</kbd>. Repeat until you have a clear view. When you have finished, simply press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide everything.

To furher improve your workflow you could assign related sets of objects to Groups. This makes it simple to select all objects within a group so you can easily select and hide whole sections at once.

Answer (score 1):

When you right click on an area with multiple objects, blender will cycle among these object.

You have several possibilities to overcome your issue:

- changing the view a little (by panning around but, even more effectively, by zooming in) in order to free up that portion of space, and make a less ambiguous click. Note: in wireframe view, the objects you select are the ones whose edges - not faces/volume - are near your mouse pointer.
- using the Outliner window, that is the top-right window in the default worktable
- using Undo: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. The Undo history contains selections as well! Note: there are separate histories for Object and Edit mode.
- [Edit, thanks Mr Zak] you can use the other selection methods that you have mentioned (<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>), provided that you then use <kbd>MMB</kbd> for the selection to make it subtractive.

However, the "selection by depth" menu <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> can help you make more precise selections.

Comment: Both Box and Circle select can be used for deselecting by pressing MMB (middle mouse button) instead of LMB when selecting. Note also that when undoing selection pressing Ctrl+Z should be done in the same interaction mode as was used when selecting (if selection was made in Object mode then in Object, Edit - in Edit mode etc).

Comment: Thank you, I had forgotten the MMB functionality. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + shift + left mouse button twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can deselect any object in object mode by selecting the camera